how do i count the number of colored cells in a row each time the color changes?
I have a grid in Excel that is 150 rows by 210 columns.  For each row, I want to know how many continuous columns of the same color.  For example, my row has 176 columns of color A, 10 columns of color B, and then 24 columns of color A.  CountIf shows that I have 200 of color A and 10 of color B.
I would like a formula or vba code that captures the number of columns of a color as the colors change.  In some rows there could be as many as 10 colors.  Some example output would be :
Row 1   Color A = 176   Color B = 10   Color A = 24
Row 2   Color A = 153   Color C = 10   Color B = 15   Color F = 24   Color A = 8
I could count them manually, but with a grid this size it could take significant time as well as introduce human error.
Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

If you use conditional formatting to colour the cells, then use countif() or counties() with the same logic.

sigh. Color is not data. It always needs a key. If you often apply a color to assign a meaning, then change that habit. Assign a value instead. It can be in a different column, a column that holds a flag. Then you can use conditional formatting to change the color of any cell in that row based on the concrete value in that flag cell. And you can use all kinds of formulas to aggregate the values in the flag column. But if you simply make a few cells yellow or green, there are no worksheet formulas that can do anything usefull with that. Change your habit and work WITH Excel instead against it.

Maybe this is helpful https://superuser.com/a/1846767/1856315

Explain in more detail what you mean. Are these colors from conditional formatting or regular formatting? Do cells, apart from color, contain any content? How do you count cells by COUNTIF? This function does not count colors in a simple way.

I was able to use the following formula to equate each color with a number
=GET.CELL(63,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE))
Now I need to count how many cells contain each color each time the number changes.  as in my example for row 1, I don't need 200 cells of color A, but the first section has 176 of color A, then 10 cells of color B, and then 24 cells of color A.  as shown in row 2 of my example, there could be multiple colors on a row, up to 10 colors.

I'd suggest a user defined function to achieve this. From what I understood, you'd like the ouput to indicate the sequence in which the columns of a certain row are colored as well as to sum up the amount of consecutive coloured rows, if their colors are equal. So trying to describe what the code to write shall do, I'd say it is to take a look at the first cell in the range that we want to inspect and then to compare its color with the color of the second cell. If the colors match, the code shall raise a counter, if the colors doesn't match, the code shall save the color of the prior cell(s) and the related counter state (always starting from 1). This shall be repeated until the last cell and the result (colors and counter states) shall be printed in another cell to be recognized by the user.
Therefore you'd first need to add a module in the VBE and give your function a name (like "Count_Consecutive_Colored_Columns"). Since you want to inspect what is going on in a certain range on the worksheet, you must custom the function in a way that the user can choose the range (like in a normal "sum" formula"). For this you need to specify an argument that your function receives from the user As Range. Since the output will be a mix of numbers and letters, I guess the functions output should be of the type String.
To look at each cell in a user selected range, you need to build a loop over the given range, starting from the first cell in it and going to the last one.
Due to the fact, that from what I understand you want the data by rows, you should limit the user input also to one row only. You can implement a message, that indicates the deny of an input of more than one row for your function and to end the function afterwards, by using an if statement to check wether the input has more than one row and to show a MsgBox if so.
The data received throughout the loop needs to be stored and you can use a string to save the interim results as the simplest solution.
Once the code collected all data, the udf prints the single entries seperated by semicolons.
The code could finally look like this (I added some comments to illustrate what the code does):
    Option Explicit

    Function Count_Consecutive_Colored_Columns(rngSelectedRange As Range) As String

    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim intFirstColumn As Integer
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim intLastColumn As Integer

    Dim strCurrentColor As String
    Dim strResult As String
    
        Application.Volatile 'Makes the function update
    
        If rngSelectedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then 'Check if more than one row was selected

            MsgBox ("Please don't select more than one row.") 'If so, warn the user and end the function
            Exit Function

        End If

        strCurrentColor = rngSelectedRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color 'get the color of the 1st cell in the selected range

        'define the loop "borders" = the first and last cell of the selected range, each +1
        intFirstColumn = rngSelectedRange.Cells(1, 1).Column + 1
        intLastColumn = rngSelectedRange.Cells(1, rngSelectedRange.Columns.Count).Column + 1
    
        intCounter = 1

        'Loop over the columns of a row, start from the second and end with the last+1
        For intIndex = intFirstColumn To intLastColumn

            'Check, if the color of the newly selected column matches the currently saved color and is not the last cell already
            If strCurrentColor = ActiveSheet.Cells(rngSelectedRange.Row, intIndex).Interior.Color _
            And Not intIndex = intLastColumn Then
                    
                intCounter = intCounter + 1 'if it matches, the count needs to be raised
                                               
            Else '= new color detected
            
                strResult = strResult & strCurrentColor & "(" & intCounter & ");" 'add new data to the string in the format: "ColorCode(quantity)"
            
                intCounter = 1 'Reset counter for next color
                strCurrentColor = ActiveSheet.Cells(rngSelectedRange.Row, intIndex).Interior.Color 'update the currentColor
        
            End If
    
        Next
        
        Count_Consecutive_Colored_Columns = Left(strResult, Len(strResult) - 1) 'Erase the last ";" from the end and output the result
        
    End Function

You can then use it like a default worksheet formula:

Let's take a look at row 4 to explain the output (here in column "W"): The code does as explained above and sums up the data of the selected range using the respective "color code" and its number of consecutive occurrences. For example "255" here means "red" and "(1)" means, that the code detected (n)one consecutive columns of red color.
If the number of colors occurring in your specific use case is finite and in case you don't like the cryptic color code, you could add a piece of code in the end, that replaces the respective code with the common color names.
Two things to bear in mind:
1. You have to update the UDF manually (e.g. by pressing F9 or by entering a cell via double click and exiting againg), as colour changes are not recognized by Excel as a potentially macro-triggering “change” event as far as I know.
2. This doesn't recognize color from conditional formatting!
Please let me know if this works for you and feel free to ask in case of any question related hereto.
